# A non-monoidal functor that respects fusion rules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, monoidal-categories

Let $(\cal{C},\otimes)$ and $(\cal{D},\odot)$ be two monoidal categories. Moreover, assume that $\cal{C}$ and $\cal{D}$ are abelian and semisimple. Let $X,Y$ be two simple objects in $\cal{C}$, and let
$$
X \otimes Y \cong Z_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Z_k,
$$
be their decomposition into simple objects. Is there a name for a  (not necessarily monoidal) functor  $f:\cal{C} \to \cal{D}$ which satisfies, for all simple $X,Y$, 
$$
f(X) \otimes f(Y) \cong f(Z_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus f(Z_k)?
$$

Comment: Trivially every additive $f$ has that property. Do you know of any non-additive functor for which this holds?

Comment: At Tobias: Sorry, there was a typo in question. It's now fixed, and the property in non longer implied by additivity.

Comment: Ah, okay! So then you probably want $f$ to be additive as well? If so, then your property is equivalent to requiring $f(A\otimes B)\cong f(A)\otimes f(B)$ for *all* objects $A$ and $B$, but without postulating any coherences, right?

Comment: Yes, I guess additivity should be assumed, and then the condition is as you put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a well-established name, but they’re called “quasi monoidal functors” in https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00645